# ASCII to String

Tags: python, ascii

I have this password generator:

```
from random import sample

character = '!"#$%&\'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{}~'
print(''.join(sample(character, 10)))
```

Example output: `bvwy2%-?/N`

However, I don't like it that the variable character is so long.

I got the content of `character` from this ASCII table:

[image]

I used every character except `|`.

**My question is how can I shorten the content of `character`?**

Something like this:

```
for i in range(33, 126):
    # get ASCII values ?
```

Comment: See the constants mentioned at the start of https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html .

Comment: @9769953 yes but I want it without the `|`

Comment: @9769953 *No you can't!*. Trying to subtract a string from another gives a `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'`. Did you mean `.replace("|", "")`?

Answer (score 2):

Since you know that your character values go from 33 to 126, you can create a string by

```
characters = "".join(chr(x) for x in range(33, 127))
```

As you noted, this contains a pipe. To remove this, simply use `str.replace()`:

```
characters = characters.replace("|", "")
```

Which gives:

```
characters = '!"#$%&\'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{}~'
```

---

However, since `random.sample()` can take *any* iterable, you could do the same thing with making `characters` a `set`. If you do this, you can have another set of disallowed characters and easily subtract the disallowed set from the all_chars set to get the allowed_chars set. For example, if you wanted to disallow pipes and quotes, you could do:

```
all_chars = set(chr(x) for x in range(33, 127))
disallowed_chars = {'|', "'", '"'}
allowed_chars = all_chars - disallowed_chars

random.sample(allowed_chars, 10) # This also works
```

Answer (score 0):

Like @9769953 told it your code could be:

```
from random import sample
import string

character = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation
character.replace('|', '') # remove the |
print(''.join(sample(character, 10)))
```